# Generating sample data from a specified model

Tags: regression, random-generation

I am reading a book on *longitudinal correlated data analysis* available in https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781420035285/generalized-estimating-equations-james-hardin-joseph-hilbe

In this book, authors introduced a custom model as,

[image]

While authors provided datasets for different model, but did not provide dataset for above model.

Could you please help on how to generate sample data from above specified model?

Your insights will be very helpful.

Comment: What is the value of $\sigma_\nu$? (It may be that this does not matter.) What are the values of `x1`? If these are of vector form, why do they not have subscripts. or are they constant (which would probably not make a lot of sense)? What are the subscripts $i$ and $t$?

Comment: @StephanKolassa This is the model specified in this book for analysis of longitudinal correlated data. Regarding some of your questions, 1) I think ${\sigma}_{\vega}$ is to be chosen such a way that $\rho = .3$ and 2) $i$ is i-th individual and $t$ corresponds to the repeated measure on each of them and those repeated measures have correlation 0.3

Comment: What kind of help are you seeking?  This seems like it's purely a programming problem.

Comment: @whuber I need help on how to generate a random sample say size of 5,000 from this `DGP`. Yes we need support from some programming language, but I am more interested to understand the algorithm to generate sample from such non-standard model

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to set up the following:

I will denote the cluster index as $t$, and the individual element of a cluster as $i$, so the $i$th measurement of the $t$th cluster is $y_{it}$. For simplicity, assume all clusters are the same size of $k$.

For each cluster $t$,

1. Sample $x_{1t}$ from a known distribution, and this is used for all $i$ observations.
2. Generate correlated noise $\nu_i$. $\nu\sim N_k(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix that contains $\sigma_d^2$ on the diagonal, and a value such that the corresponding correlation matrix is $\rho=0.3$ off the diagonal. Use your favorite multivariate normal package for this. (You could just start with a correlation matrix with 1s on the diagonal, and then fill in 0.3 off diagonal, and convert to a covariance matrix.)
3. Generate independent noise $\epsilon_{it}\sim N(0,1)$ for each observation.
4. Sum all of the above with the intercept term, and you have a vector of responses for cluster $t$.

After you simulate correlated responses for each cluster, you can just stack it into a data table, while recording the ID of the cluster. Plug into a GEE as desired.